# Is the supremum of a sequence of integrable functions finite almost everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Assume that for a sequence of measurable functions $\{f^n\}_{n\geq 1}$ there exists a constant $C$, independent of $n$, such that $\int|f^n|\mathrm{d}\mu \leq C < \infty$ for all $n \geq 1$. Is it true that $\sup_{n\geq 1}|f^n(x)|$ is finite for almost every $x$?

If we replace the assumption $\int|f^n|\mathrm{d}\mu \leq C < \infty$ by $\int|f^n|\mathrm{d}\mu < \infty$ for all $n \geq 1$, then it is not hard to find a counterexample for $\sup_{n\geq 1}|f^n(x)|$ being finite a.e. (for instance $f^n(x) = n1_{x\leq 1}$ together with the Lebesgue measure).

Also it is possible to find a sequence $f^n$ with $\int|f^n|\mathrm{d}\mu \leq C < \infty$, but $\sup_{n\geq 1} f^n \notin L^1$ (see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1241955/1052201).

I am struggling to see if the statement above is true, resp. to find a counterexample where the integrals do not grow in $n$.

Comment: To be clear:  $f^n$ is a seqeuene of functions, not powers of a fixed function $f$.

Comment: @GEdgar exactly.

Comment: Try to find a counterexample where the functions are of the form $a\mathbf1_{A}$ with $\mu(A) = 1/a$.

Comment: A standard construction that takes a little space to describe but which you may find under the heading "typewriter sequence" gives a counterexample

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich yes that works, thanks a lot!